# Notification not shown when generating request code

Tags: android, push-notification

I am facing an issue when creating notifications. I am using the AlarmManager to schedule repeating notifications.

```
val requestCode = generateRequestCode(model)

val notificationIntent = Intent(context, ReminderBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, requestCode,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis, 60000 /* One minute */, pendingIntent)
```

And this is how I generate the request code:

```
fun generateRequestCode(model: Model): Int {
    var requestCode = 0
    for (char in model.title!!) {
        requestCode += char.toInt()
    }

    return requestCode
}
```

If I use the generateRequestCode() function and pass the returned requestCode in the pendingIntent the notification won't be shown, on the other hand if I hardcode a `1` in the pendingIntent as the requestCode, it does display the notification.

Why is this happening? What am I missing?